# Issues Migrating Hibernate in Spring boot 3

Tags: java, hibernate

In my application while using spring boot 2.7.7 I was using following classes which render to database

```
org.hibernate.query.criteria.internal.CriteriaBuilder.   

org.hibernate.query.criteria.internal.ParameterRegistry.  

org.hibernate.query.criteria.internal.Renderable.  

org.hibernate.query.criteria.internal.compile.RenderingContext.
```

After upgrading to spring boot 3.0.2/Hibernate 6.0.2.

The above classes are not available.

Are these classes deprecated or package is changed for them I am unable to find.

TIA

I tried finding the classes but unable to find them or their replacement, I believe they should be available somewhere.Not sure.

Answer (score 1):

It's very simple. These classes which were deprecated since Hibernate 5 were removed in 6: https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/6.0/migration-guide.adoc#legacy-hibernate-criteria-api